# Ionic FCM push notification not received when app is opened and screen locked unless it's tapped

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

I'm developing an ionic application and I'm using FCM push notification to send notifications to the user.

This is the JSON payload of the sent notification :

```
    {
    "to" : "access_token",
    "priority": "normal",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "this is message",
      "title" : "notification Title"
    },
    "data": {
          "link": ....
     }
}
```

The push notification is received in these different cases :

- when **the app is in background or it is killed** --> the user will
  receive a system tray push notification
- when **the app is in foreground and the user is in it** --> the user will receive the new data that will update the app
- when **the app is in foreground and the screen is locked** (the system considers it as in background) --> So the user will receive a
  system tray push notification but when unlocking the screen of the phone,
  **nothing happens in the app instance that were in foreground** until I click on the push notification in the system tray.

Is there any way to get the data of a push notification that is in the system tray without clicking on it ?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this work!
For Foreground you can use **Local Notification** to show up push notification :

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/

Comment: that working well, setup icons and colors as per app. user wont even notice

Answer (score 0):

send the notification information along with data object and then , in your ionic project
manually set a notification with that data .